# Snowflake:ERROR Copy into table from File

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement to load file into snowflake table

Issue: dataframe writes each row as column names , when i was trying to fix  null values in datefield to avoid 'None' in the file

```
def execute(self, context):
    source_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id=self.source_conn_id)
    dest_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id=self.dest_conn_id)

    # Execute the SQL to fetch data from source Snowflake account
    rows = source_hook.get_records(self.sql)

    # Save data to a temporary CSV file
    #with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+', delete=False) as temp_file:
    directory = '/opt/airflow/logs/'
    filename = 'abc_test.txt'

    # Full file path
    file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

  # Convert timestamp values to a string format that Snowflake recognizes
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        row = list(row)
        for j, value in enumerate(row):
            if isinstance(value, datetime):
                row[j] = value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        rows[i] = row

    # Write data rows to the file
    with open(file_path, 'w+') as temp_file:
        df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
        print(df)
        df.to_csv(temp_file, index=False, header=False, sep='|')
```

Comment: Hi - if you prefix the name with an "@" then Snowflake understands this to be a named stage. If you want to load from a location (AWS, Azure, GCP) rather than a stage then you need to use the correct naming convention e.g. for AWS 's3://<bucket>[/<path>]'. This is all covered in the documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table

Comment: I am not using AWS or GCS to load but NamedTemporaryFile

Comment: That’s not going to work. You are running a Snowflake COPY INTO command so you have to follow the documentation for that command - you can’t use it to copy whatever you want, in whatever way you want, into Snowflake

Comment: As you’ve completely changed your question, it would have made more sense to start a new question - as now the comments against this one make no sense

Comment: Also, the first line in your question “Requirement to load file into snowflake table” makes no sense as you don’t seem to be loading data into a table any more . If you’re not going to open a new question then maybe update this one with some sample data, the result you are getting and what you want to achieve